# Java application crashes without any log

Tags: java, monitoring

I have multithreading java application works on windows server 2008 with jre1.7.
Sometimes it crashes without any log (Java proccess dies). What is the best way to catch what happenes?

Comment: Handle the exception and write in a log file by yourself

Comment: what do you mean by crash ? Is the java process killed automatically or do you see some out of memory error ?

Comment: java process killed by OS

Answer (score 2):

When you know the pid of you java application then use JDK tool jmap.

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=cheap.bin <pid>
```

Then you can analyze what happened exactly.